# Get Sitename through PowerShell script

Tags: powershell-extensions

I would like to get `SXA` Site name dynamically when we run `PowerShell` script through the context menu.
Currently I am giving static Site name in PowerShell script. Using the below code.

```
Show-Input "Enter Site name"
```

I am using multiple sites so need it dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an out of the box SXA function called **Get-SiteItem** that takes the item as parameter and gives the context site name. Using Get-Item function you can get the context item by using . as parameter.

```
Import-Function Get-SiteItem
$item = Get-Item . // Gets context item
$site =  Get-SiteItem $item // Gets context site item for the current item
Write-host $site.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command to get all your site names in your `Sitecore` Instance and then use a filter to get the specific one.

```
$siteNames = [Sitecore.Sites.SiteManager]::GetSites() | % {$_.Name}
Write-Host $siteNames | Select-Object -Unique
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This code is showing all the sites name. I would like to get only selected item Sitename through Powershell script .

Comment: Okay, can you give some more context like how you will get the selected item Sitename? Do you mean you will provide the Site item name or what? Please mention.

Comment: I am running Powershell script through context menu. We have multiple sites and every site use this script and we would like to get Sitename dynamically instead of giving it static.

Comment: Can you provide some code snippets where you are defining it as static?

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get all the sites in a list.

The list can be used in a dropdown for the user to select the site.

```
$SiteResolver = [System.Type]([Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.ISiteInfoResolver])
$Sites = [Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator]::get_ServiceProvider().GetService($SiteResolver).Sites`
| ForEach-Object { $database.GetItem($_.RootPath) }`
| Where-Object { $_ -ne $null -and $_.ID -ne $null -and $_.TemplateId -eq [Constants]::SiteTemplateId} `
| Sort-Object -Unique
```